# I need help with administrator password for macbook pro 2010 laptop

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a macbook pro from e-bay and the man that sold it told me he cleaned the computer and gave me the administrator password that wouldn’t work that I asked him for.I don’t know how to get into the computer and it was working great until I shut it down and tried starting it.When I started it up it asked for the admin.password and I put in the password that the man who sold it to me had and didn’t work.I would like to know if someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: call him and confirm the password

Answer (score 2):

Call the fellow you bought it from and ask him for the password again.

If it is a recent machine you could boot into "recovery mode" and reset the password, otherwise rebooting in single-user-mode could allow you to reset the password from the command line. Some good options are listed here:

http://tidbits.com/article/14437

Comment: Definitely the best option.